# Gradle spotbugs plugin

Tags: gradle, spotbugs

I am new to Gradle and trying to configure Spotbugs for my Spring Boot multi module project.

In my parent, build.gradle,

```gradle
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${versionSpringBoot}"
    }
}

plugins {
  id 'com.github.spotbugs' version '1.6.8'
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'pmd'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            
        }
    }

    configurations{
    }

    sourceCompatibility = '15'
    targetCompatibility = '15'

    dependencies {
    }

    pmd {
        consoleOutput = true
        toolVersion = "${versionPmd}"
        sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
        ruleSets = ["category/java/errorprone.xml", "category/java/bestpractices.xml"]
    }

    spotbugs {
        toolVersion = "${versionSpotBugs}"
        sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
    }
    
    jacoco {
        toolVersion = "${versionJacoco}"
    }

    jacocoTestReport {
        reports {
            xml.enabled = true
        }
    }

    tasks.withType(com.github.spotbugs.SpotBugsTask) {
        reports {
            xml.enabled = false
            html.enabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

Spotbugs doesn't run on running

> ./gradlew check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main issue with your build configuration is that you apply the SpotBugs plugin *only* to your root project. The following configuration solves that (leaving out configurations that are unrelated to the SpotBugs plugin for brevity):

```groovy
plugins {
    // we don’t need to *apply* the plugin to the root project, do we?
    id 'com.github.spotbugs' version '4.7.0' apply false
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    // this is the most important part, applying the plugin to the subprojects,
    // too:
    apply plugin: 'com.github.spotbugs'

    spotbugs {
        toolVersion = '4.2.2'
    }

    tasks.withType(com.github.spotbugs.snom.SpotBugsTask) {
        reports {
            xml.enabled = false
            html.enabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

With this configuration, `./gradlew check` also runs the SpotBugs tasks of subprojects (tested with Gradle 6.8.3).

Please note that I’ve also made a few other changes:

- I’m using a recent version of the plugin as the one that you’ve used (1.6.8) is several years old and doesn’t seem to work with recent versions of Gradle.
- I’ve removed the `sourceSets` configuration which is not needed and doesn’t work anyway.
- I’ve replaced the fully qualified name of the task type with an up-to-date version.

I hope this helps. Please let me know if you’re stuck with the old SpotBugs version for some reason; knowing the Gradle version that you use would help in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The below works (some adjustments to make it work locally)

gradle - 6.5.1

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.4.3"
    }
}

plugins {
  id 'com.github.spotbugs' version '4.7.0'
}

import com.github.spotbugs.snom.SpotBugsTask

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            
        }
    }

    configurations{
    }

    sourceCompatibility = '15'
    targetCompatibility = '15'

    dependencies {
    }

    spotbugs {
        toolVersion = '4.2.1'
    }
    

    tasks.withType(SpotBugsTask) {
        reports {
            xml.enabled = false
            html.enabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this in the parent module and all my code is the child modules. Is there any changes to be done in the child module? "./gradlew check" does not run anything.

Comment: what happens with `./gradlew build` ?